# ReactDom (not supported in V18) used with Datatables

Tags: reactjs, datatables

sorry because I am new in React.

I hope someone helps me to transform the following code to version 18 of React (from ReactDom.render to createRoot). I use DataTables in my React-App.

Thank you so much
Freddy

```
{
            title: "Details",
            targets: 6,
            data: null,
            createdCell: (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) => 
            ReactDOM.render(<button className='btn btn-primary' onClick ={() => (handleClick(row))}>Click</button>,td),

          },
```

some tests, without good results

Comment: [How to Upgrade to React 18](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html)

Comment: Thanks Henry for the Link but I am not able to adapt it for React 18. Maybe you can help.